# Remove certain divs by attributes conditions

Tags: html, greasemonkey

I have something like this

```
<div data-count="5">Something</div>
<div data-count="10">Something</div>
<div data-count="15">Something</div>
<div data-count="20">Something</div>
<div data-count="25">Something</div>
```

How can I remove divs where "data-count" attribute value is less than 15?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is more efficient because it only selects `div`s with the `data-count` attribute and only constructs a jQuery object once for each element:

```
$('div[data-count]').each(function () {
    var $this = $(this);

    if ($this.attr('data-count') < 15) {
        $this.remove();
    }
});
```

Demo:

```js
$('button').on('click', function () {
    $('div[data-count]').each(function () {
        var $this = $(this);

        if ($this.attr('data-count') < 15) {
            $this.remove();
        }
    });
});
```

```css
div[data-count]:before {
    content: "<div data-count=\"" attr(data-count) "\">";
}

div[data-count]:after {
    content: "</div>";
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
<button type="button">Remove data-count less than 15</button>
<div data-count="5">Something</div>
<div data-count="10">Something</div>
<div data-count="15">Something</div>
<div data-count="20">Something</div>
<div data-count="25">Something</div>
```

**An alternative solution in native JavaScript:**

```
var divs = document.querySelectorAll('div[data-count]'),
    div, i;

for (i = 0; i < divs.length; i++) {
    div = divs[i];
    if (div.getAttribute('data-count') < 15) {
        // this will not affect iteration because querySelectorAll is a non-live NodeList
        div.parentNode.removeChild(div);
    }
}
```

Demo:

```js
var button = document.querySelector('button');

button.addEventListener('click', function () {
    var divs = document.querySelectorAll('div[data-count]'),
        div, i;

    for (i = 0; i < divs.length; i++) {
        div = divs[i];
        if (div.getAttribute('data-count') < 15) {
            // this will not affect iteration because querySelectorAll is a non-live NodeList
            div.parentNode.removeChild(div);
        }
    }
});
```

```css
div[data-count]:before {
    content: "<div data-count=\"" attr(data-count) "\">";
}

div[data-count]:after {
    content: "</div>";
}
```

```html
<button type="button">Remove data-count less than 15</button>
<div data-count="5">Something</div>
<div data-count="10">Something</div>
<div data-count="15">Something</div>
<div data-count="20">Something</div>
<div data-count="25">Something</div>
```

Comment: I'm on my phone right now writing this answer and I noticed that the second demo doesn't work properly but I can't view the developer console. Can someone tell me the error so I can fix it?

Comment: Hi! The second demo is not working, but i don't have idea how to fix it, here is the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/j2d88r7g/

Comment: @Enma1011 I found the problem: `document.querySelector(All)` require attribute selectors not to contain quotes, apparently. I had mistakenly thought the opposite was true. Native JS demo works now.

Answer (score 4):

**Please try this:**

```
$('div').each(function() {
    if ( $(this).attr('data-count') < 15 ) {
        $(this).remove();
    }
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/29leinad/ypfyepaf/2/)

Answer (score 2):

This may not be the most efficient way to do it but it works:

```
function removeLowData() {
    for(var i = 1; i < 15; i++) {
        var elements = $("[data-count='" + i + "']");
        for(var j = 0; j < elements.length; j++) {
            $(elements[j]).remove(); 
           //or use .hide() if you still want them to be part of the dom but not visible
        }
    }
}
```

Just call `removeLowData()` whenever you need to remove the divs